# Encode broke on PHP through Ajax with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, utf-8

To simplify what is happening, I'm trying to send the string "Técnico" to PHP, and it is seen as "TÃ©cnico" on $_POST var.

The error is on this project alone. I have another 3 projects running on Apache2(same /var/www folder) and they don't present this problem.

Now, the complete way the data goes.

**jQuery**:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "config/inserirCargo.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        titulo: $("#titulo").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#cargo").html(data); 
    },
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' // Tried with and without
});
```

**jQuery Response**:

[image]
[image]

**PHP**:

```
var_dump($_POST['titulo']);
die();
```

My HTML already has the meta tag.

> meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"

And I've already tried these solutions alone and together:

1. AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 - on .htaccess
2. ini_set('charset', 'UTF-8'); - on php file
3. header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); - on php file
4. htmlentities($_POST['titulo']); - on php file
5. titulo: encodeURIComponent($("#titulo").val()) - on js file

And I've executed "service apache2 restart" each time done some alteration to .htacces, or used ini_set.

My PHP version is 5.5.3, to be more precise:

> PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.6 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2014 16:54:32)  Copyright
>   (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c)
>   1998-2013 Zend Technologies
>   with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies

Can someone help me?

Comment: My guess is it's being encoded to ISO-8859-1 on this line - `titulo: $("#titulo").val()`

Comment: But, how can I undo this? Using mb_detect_encoding($_POST['titulo']);, it returns 'UTF-8'. Using mb_convert_encoding($_POST['titulo'], 'UTF-8'); results in the same response as before :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys.

The problem was the charset of my Codeignter and the database.

It was set utf-8, but, the database is latin1.

Answer (score 0):

Please check php and other source files encoding.
Please check table Collation.

Comment: When used ini_get('charset'), I got 'UTF-8' as answer. The same when used mb_detect_encoding($_POST['titulo']);. Right now there is no table involved, but it's already configured. Thanks for the remind :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you use the following:

```
utf8_decode("TÃ©cnico");
```

it will return Técnico.

On server side, when you will collect `titulo` you simply have to `utf8_decode` it.
If you need to convert all your POST vars, simply pass the $_POST array to this function.

```
function utf8_decode_recursive(&$data) {
    foreach ($data as &$row) {
        $row = utf8_decode($row);
    }
}
```

So basically I guess you cannot get a normal Técnico in UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D. But I got "Tï¿½cnico" as response :/

Comment: Ooops ... It will certainly depend on the server I guess ... Let me try something else. Keep you posted.

Comment: Yup. Totally on the server, and it's not even Apache2 fault. I have another 3 projects that runs on the same /var/www folder, and neither present the same problem.